# JSFL - reading metadata onDocumentChanged

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, jsfl

I am building a flash panel that reads metadata from a .fla when it is active in the Flash IDE. This panel is also storing metadata in the .fla and that is no problem. What is problematic is that I do not know how to stop the event listener from listening for onDocumentChange.

I want it to listen for it as long as it is open, but when it's closed it should clean up after itself because trying to read metadata every time a new document is selected is not a very nice thing to do.

I have tried to listen for all kind of events in the panel to detect when the user closes it, but with no success.

Anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a lot of work with Events in JSFL, and the sad truth is that the system is flawed. Document events are fine, but layer and frame events are very unreliable; executing in the wrong order, layer events not firing when you come out of an edit, etc, etc.

Polling from the panel is often the best way to do it, and is not such a performance hit.

Document events however, are OK. The documentation on how to remove them is incorrect, see Dru Kepple's post here on what you should do:

http://summitprojectsflashblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/jsfl-get-fl-removeeventlistener-to-work/

Comment: But, after reading my question again, I still do not know WHEN to remove it. if I close the panel (which I cannot detect), and open it again, it adds a new listener and the old one still fires. However, the ID seem to increase by one every time and I guess that it starts on 0, so I could always try to remove the listener with id 0, but that would not work if another panel with the same functionality is in use... Someway I need to now either when the panel is closed or at least be able to check if it is open..

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if you can store metadata in the .fla (or have some sort of unique ID anyway) you could check in the event listener if the document with that is still open somehow?

So basically fingerprint the .fla and before doing any work in the listener check for the existence to see if the file is open. If not, remove the listener, if yes, fire away the normal event handling.

Comment: Thanks for your idea but the problem is that I need to check all documents for metadata as long as the panel is open.

Comment: Is that a resource intensive thing to do? I guess you would be fine doing it on a relatively low frequency like 1-2 secs or perhaps even more as this is a sort of garbage collection job?

Comment: It won't be intensive at all, just felt bad to keep a listener active when the panel is not even open. And in general it would be nice to know if there is a way to know when a panel is closed, if you need to clean up something else .

Comment: My suggestion was to do this periodical metadata check to find out if the document is still open and if not, remove the listener and do any other cleanup, as a form of manual garbage collection. Not ideal, but if there's no built in notification for closure then it's still nicer than not checking at all :)

Comment: Ok, now I get where u at, polling the current opened document to see if there is a new one opened (with new metadata). Actually that might be a better idea anyway. But I wonder if I am able to stop this polling from running even if the panel is closed...

Answer (score 0):

Within your listener function include another function which loops through all swf panels in the IDE, checking if the name of your panel exists. If it doesn't then remove your listener and return out of your listener function.

```
function myListenerFunction () {
    if ( !checkForPanel( myPanelName ) ) {
        fl.removeEventListener( type, eventID );
        return;
    }
}

function checkForPanel( arg_panelName ) {

    var target_panelName = arg_panelName;   
    var target_panelsArr = fl.swfPanels;

    var i;
    var iLen = target_panelsArr.length;
    var _swfPanel;
    for ( i = 0; i < iLen; i++ ) {

        _swfPanel = target_panelsArr[i];

        if ( (_swfPanel.name) == target_panelName ) {
            return true;
        }       
    }

    return false;
}
```